# Replace multiple char in one statement

Tags: python, string, replace

I want to replace the following chars with their corresponding values (from the dictionary) in one string:

```
dictVal = 
{
'a' : 'W',
'p' : 2,
'd' : 5
}
```

Is there a more elegant way of doing this instead of iterating over ever key of the dictionary?

For example:

```
input string = 'Please help me'
output string = 'PleWse hel2 me'
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the output you are expecting? and what did you try until now?

Comment: What char do you want to replace? Show your expected output.

Comment: I have tried to apply replace statement one by one in loop for each key in dict.

Comment: Use `translate`: `'Please help me'.translate({ord(key): str(value) for key, value in dictVal.items()})`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to iterate over the dictionary, you can simply iterate over the string and check if the character is present in the dictionary.

```
# using d as the variable instead of dict because dict is a keyword
d = {'a': 'W', 'p': 2, 'd': 5}
s = "Please help me"
new_s = ""

for c in s:
    # str(...) because you have numbers as values in the dictionary
    new_s += str(d.get(c, c))

# Output: PleWse hel2 me
print(new_s)
```

Or, you can use a list comprehension like this:

```
new_s = ''.join(str(char_mapping.get(c, c)) for c in s)
```

To understand more on dictionary.get(key, default_value), read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey).

Comment: You can also summarise that in a list comprehension, like:
`new_s = ''.join(str(char_mapping.get(c, c)) for c in s)`